# Detect Keypress event in TinyMCE Text Area

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, tinymce

I already successfully embedded a TinyMCE text editor in a text area in Drupal 7 Form API.
I tried pasting the code below in my javascript code, with no luck.

```
tinyMCE.init({         
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onKeyPress.add(function(ed, e) {
            console.debug('Key press event: ' + e.keyCode);
        });
    }
});
```

There's no errors but only warning, everytime I type on the textarea:

```
'KeyboardEvent.keyLocation' is deprecated. Please use 'KeyboardEvent.location' instead.
```

How will I fix the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this link: https://www.drupal.org/node/1714068

Paste the code below in your .module file.

```
/**
* Implements hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter().
*/
function MODULENAME_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context){    
     if($context['profile']->editor == 'tinymce') {          
         drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME') . '/MODULENAME_tinymce_callbacks.js');
         $settings['setup'] = 'MODULENAME_tinymce_setup_callback';           
     }
}
```

In MODULENAME_tinymce_callbacks.js

```
 function MODULENAME_tinymce_setup_callback(ed){ 
     var range = 0;
     ed.onEvent.add(function (ed, e) {
         range = ed.selection.getRng().startOffset;  
         console.log(range);
     });
 }
```

The cursor position will then be log in the console of the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Please update your TinyMCE plugin to latest version. It looks that you are using an old version of TinyMCE which do not support latest jQuery or latest browsers.
If you have updated your TinyMCE plugin then disable your theme and enable default drupal theme/template and check again.

hope this will help you